# Для чего в Python несколько функций для поиска в регулярных выражениях?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Выражение `re.match("regexp", str)` полностью идентично `re.search("^regexp", str)`. И есть еще `re.findall()`. Зачем плодить сущности без надобности?

Как же насчет "There should be one — and preferably only one — obvious way to do it."?

Edit: в питоне 3.4 (март 2014) добавили еще `re.fullmatch()`, идентичный `re.search("^regexp$", str)`

Comment: А вот и не идентично. "*Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.*". findall же вообще находит все вхождения, которые есть. Но питон, конечно, по своей сущности странный язык.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вы в каждый вопрос забегаете и это пишете? Или это бот такой? Когда я увижу **исчерпывающий** ответ, я так и сделаю.

Comment: По-моему, тут потёрли все мои свежие коменты, больше писать ничего не буду.

Answer (score 15):

Эти функции несут в себе различную семантику. То же самое можно сказать и про `2 + 2 + 2` vs `2 * 3` или (с натяжкой) про синонимы. Можно заменить `2*3` через `2 + 2 + 2`, равно как и `re.findall` написать через `re.search`, но это потребует определенных телодвижений.

### re.match

Сопоставляет строку с образцом. Сопоставление происходит с начала текста. За счет этого, функция `re.match` потенциально быстрее, потому что она точно знает, где начать поиск.

```
In [31]: re.match('a', 'aa')
Out[31]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>

In [32]: re.match('a', 'ba') # Returns None

In [33]: re.match('a$', 'aa') # Returns None

In [34]: re.match('aa$', 'aa')
Out[34]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='aa'>

In [35]: re.match('b', 'a\nb\nc', re.MULTILINE) # Returns None

In [36]: re.match('ab', 'a\nb\nc', re.MULTILINE) # Returns None

In [37]: re.match('a\nb\n', 'a\nb\nc', re.MULTILINE)
Out[37]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='a\nb\n'>
```

### re.search

Ищет первое вхождение образца в строку. Если флаг `re.MULTILINE` не включен, символы `^` и `$` определяют соответственно начало и конец текста, в противном случае - начало и конец строки. Пример:

```
In [12]: re.search('^b', 'a\nb\nc\n') # Returns None

In [13]: re.search('b$', 'a\nb\nc\n') # Returns None

In [14]: re.search('^b', 'a\nb\nc\n', re.MULTILINE)
Out[14]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='b'>

In [15]: re.search('b$', 'a\nb\nc\n', re.MULTILINE)
Out[15]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='b'>
```

### re.findall

Находит все неперекрывающие соответствия (возвращает список объектов `str`):

```
In [24]: re.findall('aa', 'aaa')
Out[24]: ['aa']

In [25]: re.findall('aa', 'aaaa')
Out[25]: ['aa', 'aa']
```

---

<sub>По мотивам [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806772/1532460) на SO</sub>

Еще одно важное различие, касающееся только функций `re.RegexObject.match` и `re.RegexObject.search`. Обе сигнатуры позволяют передать опциональный параметр `pos`, начиная с которого будет производиться поиск. Стоит отметить, что это не совсем то же самое, что и срез строки, поскольку символ `^` по-прежнему будет определять настоящее начало строки. Пример различного поведения:

```
In [38]: s
Out[38]: 'a ab abc abcd'

In [39]: re.compile('a').match(s, pos=2)
Out[39]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='a'>

In [40]: re.compile('^a').match(s, pos=2) # None
```

Это может быть полезно, если мы пишем парсер, который не должен пропускать неизвестные символы:

```
In [41]: def tokenize_match(s, patt):
   ....:        at = 0
   ....:        while at < len(s):
   ....:                m = patt.match(s, pos=at)
   ....:                if not m:
   ....:                        raise ValueError("Did not expect character at location {}".format(at))
   ....:                at = m.end()
   ....:                yield m
   ....:
```

Функция `tokenize_search` определена аналогичным образом, за исключением того, что используется `patt.search` а не `patt.match`:

```
In [42]: list(tokenize_search('ab421"cdef', re.compile('(ab)|\d|\w')))
Out[42]: 
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='ab'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='4'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 4), match='2'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 5), match='1'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 7), match='c'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 8), match='d'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 9), match='e'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(9, 10), match='f'>]

In [43]: list(tokenize_match('ab421"cdef', re.compile('(ab)|\d|\w')))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-de312181f0b5> in <module>()
----> 1 list(tokenize_match('ab421"cdef', re.compile('(ab)|\d|\w')))

<ipython-input-41-9d359a5ad10e> in tokenize_match(s, patt)
      4                 m = patt.match(s, pos=at)
      5                 if not m:
----> 6                         raise ValueError("Did not expect character at location {}".format(at))
      7                 at = m.end()
      8                 yield m

ValueError: Did not expect character at location 5
```

Видим, что функция `tokenize_search` пропустила незнакомый элемент, в отличие от `tokenize_match`.

Comment: Ух как ты классно накопипастил из официальной документации, и оформил прикольно! На вопрос, правда, не ответил, но кого это волнует, вон 8 плюсов получил.

Comment: В таком случае, Вы можете уточнить вопрос, указав, почему (по Вашему мнению) данный ответ не является полным, либо оставить более содержательный комментарий.

Comment: В ответе 95% копипасты из документации, не отвечающей на вопрос, например, зачем было делать match и search. Все еще не содержательно?

Comment: Добавил описание различного поведения функций `match` и `search`, а также пример использования (по мотивам [этого ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29806772/1532460) на SO)

Comment: Внес значительные правки в Ваш ответ исключительно с целью повышения его качества. Вы неправильно отражаете суть флага мультилайн.

Comment: Кратко причина: Вы слишком заостряете внимание на метасимволе `^` и создается ложное впечатление, что этот метасимвол по-разному обрабатывается различными функциями в зависимости от наличия флага multiline. На самом деле поведение меняется не из-за функций, а из-за флага. Это обычное поведение метасимволов `^$` при наличии флага multiline или же его отсутствии.

Comment: @ReinRaus, согласен, неудачный пример. Сейчас долго сидел, много думал, зачем я вообще включил этот пример и что хотел им сказать. Так и не придумал. Спасибо за рецензию.

Comment: Не за что. Всегда рад помочь, если могу, тем кто старается.

Comment: Ещё пример: `2**3`, можно как `2*2*2` написать.

Comment: Какой строгий ОП в этом вопросе )

Comment: @jfs только никто так не делает без причины.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: в этом смысл и состоит, что не смотря на то, что `2**3` можно записать как `2*2*2` это ещё не значит, что `**` не должен существовать, даже если нас интересуют только маленькие положительные целые степени (это к вопросу о том, зачем нужны функции такие как `re.findall()`, не смотря на то, что есть более примитивные функции (`re.search()`), которые позволили и так результат получить (аналог: `**` <-> `findall()`, `*` <-> `search()`).

Answer (score 7):

<sup>более краткая версия [@soon ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431846/23044):</sup>

Существенной разницы между *функциями* `re.search` и `re.match` нет. Легко можно [одну выразить через другую](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806773/4279). Кроме удобства, вероятно они существуют потому что *метод* [`SRE_Pattern.search` в отличии от *метода* `SRE_Pattern.match` не позволяет выразить: "искать с текущей позиции"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806772/4279):

- `\A` ищет с начала строки
- `^` ищет с начала строки и с начала каждой новой строки (последнее только c включенным `re.MULTILINE` флагом)

Текущая позиция не обязаны быть в начале строки или начале новой строки, поэтому `match` и `search` ведут себя по разному:

```
>>> import re
>>> search = re.compile(r'\Ax').search
>>> match = re.compile(r'x').match
>>> text = 'xxx'
>>> search(text, pos=2) # not found
>>> match(text, pos=2) # found
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='x'>
```

Другие функции такие как `re.findall()` существуют для удобства, так же как удобней написать `2**3` вместо `2*2*2`.

---

> *"There should be one — and preferably only one — obvious way to do it."*

Три различных ситуации -- три функции, которые являются *очевидным* решением в каждом случае:

- `re.match` удобно использовать, если с начала строки хочется искать (неявный `\A`): аналог `text.startwith(prefix)`
- `re.search` рекомендуется использовать для поиска по всей строке: аналог `substr in text`
- `re.fullmatch` когда строка целиком должна соответствовать шаблону (неявные `\A`, `\Z`): аналог `text == another`. `re.fullmatch()` функция добавлена в Python 3.4 -- [частный случай считается достаточно распространённым (и разница между `$` и `\Z` достаточно тонкой для новичков), чтобы отдельную функцию завести](http://bugs.python.org/issue16203).

Comment: "Три различных ситуации -- три функции, которые являются очевидным решением в каждом случае:" - а где функция для поиска  в конце строки? Добавят в 3.5? Могу еще парочку сценариев придумать. Так и до пхп можно докатиться, где сортировка в обычном и обратном порядке - 2 разные функции.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Питон прагматичный язык: если *на практике* такие случаи могут по Вашему мнению часто встречаться, то Вы можете предложить новую функцию на http://bugs.python.org или сперва на python-ideas списке рассылке обсудить. Почитайте как обосновано добавление [`re.fullmatch()`](http://bugs.python.org/issue16203) (кратко -- это улучшает читаемость кода и уменьшает вероятность багов), предложение внёс Guido van Rossum (BDFL).

Comment: Ну фуллматч еще как-то можно обосновать, но match-то зачем? "Somehow the $ gets lost" - офигительный аргумент. А для findall тоже аналоги не помешало бы наклепать.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Я не думаю, что более глубокий аргумент существует, кроме уже приведённых. В теории `matching from start` и `searching in a string` разные операции и практика показывает, что полезно иметь match и search отдельно (использование обоих операцих примерно одинаковое ).

Comment: @SmitJohnth: 2. `re.fullmatch()` уменьшает вероятность ошибки ("$ get lost"), более явно выражает *намерение* программиста. Не нужно с высока смотреть, на простые ошибки. Ошибаются все. Только идиоты думают что они непогрешимы. 3. Про `findall()` не понял (есть `finditer()`). `findall()` это как `search()` в цикле. `\A`,`\Z` имеют мало смысла в этом случае.

Comment: "$ get lost" - с такой же вероятностью может потеряться отступ, строчка кода. Крайне невнятный аргумент. "практика показывает, что полезно иметь match и search отдельно" - какая практика? Моя практика - у меня был затык из-за того, что перепутал search и match. "findall() это как search()" - теперь по логике вещей надо добавить то же для match и matchfull.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: 1. Верно, что введение `fullmatch()` не спасает от всех ошибок. **Ничто** не спасёт. Это не значит, что нельзя уменьшить вероятность *определённых* (не всех сразу) ошибок. 2. практика (реальный код, написанный реальными людьми): например, сравните сколько раз `re.search` vs. `re.match` используется (я посмотрел на github, у себя на локальном диске). 3. Ещё раз: `\A`, `\Z` имеют мало смысла для `findall()` (поэтому нет логики, чтобы добавить match и matchfull для `findall()`). Хотя некоторый аналог для `\G` можно рассмотреть.

Comment: 1. Можно уменьшать количество разных потенциальных ошибок до бесконечности, при этом засоряя модуль. Как по мне, оно того не стоило. В "фрактале плохого дизайна" был пример функции типа "убрать html теги и сделать еще что-то", или регекспы в пхп с e флагом, которые экзекают результат. Более того, насколько я знаю, питон тут единственный с этим сомнительным нововведением. 2. У меня матч, кажется, ни разу. Сейчас использую findall.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: В крайности впадать не надо. Научи дурака Богу молиться — он себе лоб расшибёт. Всё хорошо в меру. Практика (миллионы вызовов в коде на github) не согласна с Вами. Это не нововедение. [`match` был с самого начала c Питона 1.5](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/lib/matching-searching.html), когда адаптировали `pcre`.

Comment: Это нововведение по сравнению с тем же перлом, откуда и уперли регекспы. А где крайности-то?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: До Питона 1.5 regex модуль присутствовал с Emacs-синтаксисом. В этом модуле также разделение есть [match vs. search](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/lib/Contents_of_Module_regex.html). Но это не важно. С тех пор прошло много времени и как match так и search доказали свою полезность. Крайность называть добавление `fullmatch()` засорением модуля (в части мест, где я использовал `match()` более точно можно было бы использовать `fullmatch()`). За 20 лет API непереполнилось. Я знал perl до Python поэтому понимаю, что может быть не превычно сперва, ну и Python не для каждого.

Comment: "Python не для каждого" - громковатое заявление. Типа, кому не нравится, что аж три функции для поиска по регекспам - можете валить? Сами валите.  От fullmatch прока, кстати, больше, чем от match, да и название намекает на то, что это не просто поиск.

Comment: Вы не поняли. "Не для каждого" значит что разным людям разные языки могут подходить.  Значения "валить" я не вкладывал.  Например, для меня Ruby более красивый язык, но я предпочитаю программировать на Python из-за более явного "скучного" кода, менее магического. Три функции очевидно недостаточно, чтобы решение принять, но если постоянно приходится бороться с широко используемыми интерфейсами, то стоит на альтернативы посмотреть (без серьёзных оснований существующее API никуда не уйдёт). Meta: *assume good faith and be nice*

Comment: В дзене питона явно указано, что нехрен плодить сущности на ровном месте. Вот для руби подход бы вполне подошел. "Три функции очевидно недостаточно, чтобы решение принять" - да, но тем не менее, это недостаток. Не настолько большой,чтобы из-за него бросить питон, но все же.